# Postgres trigger and row locking

Tags: postgresql, locking, database-trigger

Please help with my understanding of how triggers and locks can interact

I bulk load records to a table with statements something like this…..

```
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO table_a VALUES (record1) , (record2), (record3)………;
INSERT INTO table_a VALUES (record91) , (record92), (record93)………;
…..
….
COMMIT;
```

There can be several hundred records in a single insert, and there can be several dozen INSERT statements between COMMITs

Table_a has a trigger on it defined as….

```
AFTER INSERT ON table_a FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE foo();
```

The procedure *foo()* parses each new row as it’s added, and will (amongst other stuff) update a record in a summary *table_b* (uniquely identified by primary key).  So, for every record inserted into *table_a* a corresponding record will be updated in *table_b*

I have a 2nd process that also attempts to (occasionally) update records in *table_b*. On very rare occasions it may attempt to update the same row in *table_b* that the bulk process is updating

**Questions** – should anything in the bulk insert statements affect my 2nd process being able to update records in *table_b*? I understand that the bulk insert process will obtain a row lock each time it updates a row in *table_b*, but when will that row lock be released? – when the individual record (record1, record2, record3 etc etc) has been inserted? Or when the entire INSERT statement has completed? Or when the COMMIT is reached?

**Some more info** - my overall purpose for this question is to try to understand why my 2nd process occasionally pauses for a minute or more when trying to update a row in table_b that is also being updated by the bulk-load process. What *appears* to be happening is that the lock on the target record in *table_b* isn't actually being released until the COMMIT has been reached - which is contrary to what I think ought to be happening. (I think a row-lock should be released as soon as the UPDATE on that row is done)

---

UPDATE after answer(s) - yes of course you're both right. In my mind I had somehow convinced myself that the individual updates performed within the trigger were somehow separate from the overall BEGIN and COMMIT of the whole transaction. Silly me.

The practice of adding multiple records with one INSERT, and multiple INSERTs between COMMITs was introduced to improve the bulk load speed (which it does) I had forgotten about the side-effect of increasing the time before locks would be released.

Comment: A lock is **only** released when the transaction that obtained the lock is completed - either by commit or rollback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What should happen when the transaction is rolled back? It is rather obvious that all inserts on `table_a,` as well as all updates on `table_b,` should be rolled back. This is why all rows of `table_b` updated by the trigger will be locked until the transaction completes.

Committing after each `insert` (reducing the number of rows inserted in a single transaction) will reduce the chance of conflicts with concurrent processes.