# PSQLException and lock issue when trigger added on table

Tags: postgresql, triggers, locking

UPDATE: I eliminated Hibernate from the problem. I completely reworked description of problem to simplify it as much as possible.

I have `master` table with noop trigger and `detail` table with two relations between `master` and `detail` table:

```sql
create table detail (
  id bigint not null,
  code varchar(255) not null,
  primary key (id)
);

create table master (
  id bigint not null,
  name varchar(255),
  detail_id bigint, -- "preferred" detail is one-to-one relation
  primary key (id),
  unique (detail_id),
  foreign key (detail_id) references detail(id)
);

create table detail_candidate ( -- "candidate" details = many-to-many relation modeled as join table
  master_id bigint not null,
  detail_id bigint not null,
  primary key (master_id, detail_id),
  foreign key (detail_id) references detail(id),
  foreign key (master_id) references master(id)
);

create or replace function trgf() returns trigger as $$
begin
  return NEW;
end;
$$ language 'plpgsql';

create trigger trg
  before insert or update
  on master
  for each row execute procedure trgf();

insert into master (id, name) values (1000, 'x'); -- this is part of database setup
insert into detail (code, id) values ('a', 1);    -- this is part of database setup
```

In such setup, I open two terminal windows with `psql` and perform following steps:

1. in first terminal, change master (leave transaction open)

```sql
begin;
update master set detail_id=null, name='y' where id=1000;
```

2. in second terminal, add detail candidate to master in own transaction

```sql
begin;
set statement_timeout = 4000;
insert into detail_candidate (master_id, detail_id) values (1000, 1);
```

Last command in second terminal timeouts with message

```
ERROR:  canceling statement due to statement timeout
CONTEXT:  while locking tuple (0,1) in relation "master"
SQL statement "SELECT 1 FROM ONLY "public"."master" x WHERE "id" OPERATOR(pg_catalog.=) $1 FOR KEY SHARE OF x"
```

My observation and questions (changes are independent):

- *when the db is setup without trigger, i.e. `drop trigger trg on master;` is called after initial setup, everything works fine*.
  Why the presence of noop trigger has such an influence? I don't get it.
- *when the db is setup without unique constraint on `master.detail_id` (i.e. `alter table master drop constraint master_detail_id_key;` is called after initial setup), everything works fine too*. Why?
- *when I omit explicit `detail=null` assignment in update statement in first terminal (since there's null value from setup anyway), everything works fine too*. Why?

Tried on Postgres 9.6.12 (embedded), 9.6.15 (in Docker), 11.5 (in Docker).

Problem is reproducible in Docker image `tomaszalusky/trig-example` which is available on DockerHub or can be built from [this Dockerfile](https://gist.github.com/tomaszalusky/4b953c678c806408025d05d984d30ed3) (instructions inside).

---

**UPDATE 2:** I found common behaviour of three observation above. I spawned the query `select * from pgrowlocks('master')` from [pgrowlocks extension](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgrowlocks.html) in second transaction. The [row-level lock](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/explicit-locking.html#LOCKING-ROWS) of updated row in `master` is `FOR UPDATE` in failing case but `FOR NO KEY UPDATE` in all three working cases. This is in perfect compliance with [mode match table in documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/explicit-locking.html#ROW-LOCK-COMPATIBILITY) since `FOR UPDATE` mode is the stronger one and mode requested by insert statement is `FOR KEY SHARE` (which is apparent from error message, also invoking the `select ... for key share` command has same effect as `insert` command).

The documentation on `FOR UPDATE` mode says:

> The FOR UPDATE lock mode is also acquired by (...) an UPDATE that modifies the values on certain columns. Currently, the set of columns considered for the UPDATE case are those that have a unique index on them that can be used in a foreign key (...)

It is true for `master.detail_id` column. However, still it's not clear why `FOR UPDATE` mode isn't chosen independently on trigger presence and why trigger presence caused it.

Comment: I posted question to pg hackers forum - https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/20190903145602.F566C141%40centrum.cz .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interesting problem. This is my best guess. I have tested none of it.

Generally speaking, postgres's educated guessing of what effect statements will have on data does not extend into trigger logic. When executing the second statement, postgres sees the foreign key constraint, and knows it has to check if the value being assigned (inserted) is valid, that is, if it represents a valid key in the foreign table. It is possible, however bad practice, that the trigger may have an effect on the validity of the foreign key being proposed (e.g. if the trigger deletes records).

(case 1) If there is no trigger, then it can look at the data (both pre-commit and staged for commit) and decide if the proposed value is gauranteed valid. (case 2) If there is no FK constraint, then the trigger cannot impact the validity of the insertion, so it is allowed. (case 3) If you omit the `detail_id=null`, there is no change in the update so the trigger won't fire, so its presence is irrelevant.

I try to avoid both FK constraints and triggers whenever possible. It's better, in my opinion, to let the database accidentally contain partially incorrect data then to have it hang completely, like you're seeing here. I would drop all FK constraints and triggers, and force all update and insert operations to operate via stored functions, which perform validation inside a begin/commit lock, and handle incorrect/invalid insert/update attempts appropriately and immediately, rather than forcing postgres to wait for command 1 to commit before deciding if command 2 is allowed.

**Edit:** see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53109765/postgres-trigger-and-row-locking)

**Edit 2:** The closest thing that I can find to official documentation around the timing of triggers relative to the checking of constraints is this from the [triggers docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-createtrigger.html)

> The trigger can be specified to fire before the operation is attempted on a row (before constraints are checked and the INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE is attempted); or after the operation has completed (after constraints are checked and the INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE has completed); or instead of the operation (in the case of inserts, updates or deletes on a view). If the trigger fires before or instead of the event, the trigger can skip the operation for the current row, or change the row being inserted (for INSERT and UPDATE operations only).

This is a bit unclear, if the trigger happening before the constraint check applies to constraint check of other transactions. Whatever the case, this issue is either a bug or poorly documented.

Comment: I asked the question on pg hackers forum (see comment under question) and received Álvaro Herrera's (author of locks) answer. The way how rowlock level is determined is different for case with and without trigger, on execution path level. With trigger, set of columns treated as key column is computed from pk/uk columns as doc specifies. Without trigger, db performs some optimizations - in this case it recognizes the `set detail_id=null` statement is actually no change, hence it chooses weaker lock level. Anyway your answer is pretty close and I appreciate your effort, so I accept it. Thanks!